# How to dynamically increase table index based on pagination in Angular 8

Tags: angular, indexing, pagination

I'm testing pagination in Angular 8 but my table index does not change with page number change.
In AgularJS I know how to use $watch and serial but I have no idea how to make the table index change dynamically.
In my table, item per page is 20, so when I'm on page 2 I want index 21 - 40 e.g.
How do I get that? See my code example below.

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let book of books$ | paginate: { itemsPerPage: count, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
<td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
<td>{{book.name}}</td>
</tr>
<!--Including the pagination control.-->
<div class="text-right">
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
// Pagination parameters.
p: Number = 1;
count: Number = 20;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
return this.http.get<any>(this.bookUrl)
   .subscribe(data => this.books$ = data);
}
```

Pagination works fine, I only need help with dynamic indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arithmetics:

```
{{ (p - 1) * count + i + 1 }}
```

If you're on page 3, `p` is 3, so `(p - 1)` is 2, so `(p - 1) * count` is 40, so the indices will start at 41 (for `i` = 1).

Comment: Can you show the usage of your code, because when I placed the ur suggestion in my td, the was error: "Expected a numeric type"

Comment: Not sure where this error come from, but I'd bet on the fact that you're using `Number` instead of `number`.

Comment: Maybe you could help me with this question, the pangination works normal for the datatable when I fetched all data through my url. To get some data with certain keyword through input field and button, I created a function: e.g search(){'url' + keyword}. The question now is, why pagination does not work for returned data, it simply show page 1, but my item are more that the "count".

Comment: Sorry, I'm not smart enough to find a bug in your code without seeing the code. Post another question, with all the relevant code. A complete reproducible example as a stackblitz would be ideal as a companion of that new question.